# Asynchrony with Kafka C# Client

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, apache-kafka

I am trying to use Kafka for a pub/sub architecture in a .NET Core project. But Confluent's Kafka c# client only offers a synchronous "`Consume`" method for listening to published messages. Here is the sample code the provide on how to use this client:

```
var conf = new ConsumerConfig
    { 
        GroupId = "test-consumer-group",
        BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
        AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
    };

using (var c = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(conf).Build())
{
    c.Subscribe("my-topic");

    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Console.CancelKeyPress += (_, e) => {
        e.Cancel = true; // prevent the process from terminating.
        cts.Cancel();
    };

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var cr = c.Consume(cts.Token);
                Console.WriteLine($"Consumed message '{cr.Value}' at: '{cr.TopicPartitionOffset}'.");
            }
            catch (ConsumeException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error occured: {e.Error.Reason}");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        // Ensure the consumer leaves the group cleanly and final offsets are committed.
        c.Close();
    }
}
```

I am trying to make this call asynchronous. I tried using `Task.Run` and `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`. They both work in terms of asynchrony but I see that they both use a worker thread where the "`Consume`" method sits idle waiting for a message. I would like to create asynchrony without having an idle thread most of the time. As far as I know, the `async/await` structure queues up the tasks and thus is able to create asynchrony without the additional burden of a thread. How would it be possible in my case?

I thought `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` would do the trick and only when `Consume` is signalled would a thread from the threadpool be used to continue the execution of the remainder code but I see `Consume` waiting idle in its own thread.

Comment: Not possible, since the underlying API is synchronous, it will consume a thread until completed.  This doesn't necessarily mean that the thread is doing work and consuming CPU time, it just means there's a thread that may or may not be active.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Silverback: http://silverback-messaging.net. It's a library I wrote and is used in quite a few applications/services. It internally uses Confluent.Kafka but will take care of connecting with Kafka and implement the consume loop in a separate thread (among many other things). The resulting code will be something like this:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddSilverback()
            .WithConnectionToMessageBroker(options => options.AddKafka())
            .AddKafkaEndpoints(
                endpoints => endpoints
                    .Configure(
                        config =>
                        {
                            config.BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";
                        })
                .AddInbound(
                    endpoint => endpoint
                        .ConsumeFrom("my-topic")
                        .DeserializeJson(serializer => serializer.UseFixedType<SomeMessage>())
                        .Configure(
                            config =>
                            {
                                config.GroupId = "test-consumer-group";
                                config.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                            })))

            .AddSingletonSubscriber<MySubscriber>();
    }
}

public class MySubscriber
{
    public Task OnMessageReceived(SomeMessage message)
    {
        // TODO: process message
    }
}
```

It relies on Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, so if you want to use it in a console application you will still need to create the IServiceCollection/IServiceProvider.